# Python- How to sort a dictionary within a file and output specific format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have created a function that

1. opens a file for writing (filename)
2. Given a dictionary to write into that file (d)
3. Needs to return the sorted dictionary (asciibetically,) as a string in this format:

   > Every  key-value   pair    of  the dictionary
   >   should  be  output  as: a   string  that    starts  with    key,    followed    by  ":",    a   tab,    then    the integers    from    the 
   >   value   list.       Every   integer should  be  followed    by  a   "," and a   tab except  for the very    last    one,    which   should  be  followed    by  a   newline.

So it should look something like this:

```
d   =   {'orange':[1,3],'apple':[2]}

"apple:\t2\norange:\t1,\t3\n"
```

How do I sort the keys of the dictionary asciibetically and get this specific string output? This is where I'm stuck. I know I should use sorted() somewhere but all I've tried has led to errors.

Here is my current function:

```
def store(d,filename):
    addfile= open('filename', 'w')
    for key, values in d.items():
        line='{},{}'.format(key,values)
        addfile.write(line, file= addfile)
    addfile.close()
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def format_item(key, value):
    return key + ":\t" + ",\t".join(str(x) for x in value)

def format_dict(d):  # returns a sorted list of lines
    return sorted(format_item(key, value) for key, value in d.items())

def store(d, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write("\n".join(format_dict(d)))
```

Comment: What do you mean, @kg123? You call `store` - giving it `d`. It then passes `d` to `format_dict` (which further utilises `format_item`). Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Cool! Feel free to ask further if something's still not clear, or to accept the answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: So this is giving me false is not true as a result?

Comment: @kg123: It will help if you paste the exact thing you try and the exact output you get. Otherwise there's nothing I (or most likely anyone) can do.

Comment: Please see edited question that now includes exactly what I did.

Comment: What's in the file? What's expected to be there? What does `check_content` do?

Comment: There are just strings in the file. Check content sees if there's even strings there, I believe.